# Numba: Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected

Tags: numpy, scipy, numba

I am trying to compile python function with numba @jit. In the argument list, N1,N2,N3 are integers, FX,FY,FZ are numpy matrices with float64 data type,inx,...,ground is numpy array with int64 datatype, and inb,res has int64 data type. In below function, spdiags, lil_matrix,csx_matrix are from scipy.sparse library.

```
@jit
def ThreeDChannel_Differentiate1(N1,N2,N3,FX,FY,FZ,
                                 inx,iny,inz,A0,AN,AS,AE,AW,AA,AG,east,
                                 west,north,south,air,ground,inb,res):

    data = np.zeros((7,(N1*N2*(N3-2))))
    diags = np.array([-N1*(N3-2), -N1, -1, 0, 1, N1, N1*(N3-2)])
    M = spdiags(data, diags, N1*N2*(N3-2), N1*N2*(N3-2))
    #M = sp.csc_matrix(M)
    M = sp.lil_matrix(M)

    for k in inz-1:
        for j in inx:
            for i in iny:
                FY0 = FY[i,j,k+1]
                FYN = FY[north[i],j,k+1]
                FYS = FY[south[i],j,k+1]

                FX0 = FX[i,j,k+1]
                FXE = FX[i,east[j],k+1]
                FXW = FX[i,west[j],k+1]

                FZ0 = FZ[i,j,k+1]
                FZA = FZ[i,j,air[k]]
                FZG = FZ[i,j,ground[k]]

                if inb == 1:
                    M[A0[i,j,k],A0[i,j,k]] = 1/FY0*(FYN/(FY0+FYN)-FYS/(FYS+FY0))

                if inb == 2:
                    M[A0[i,j,k],A0[i,j,k]] = 1/FX0*(FXE/(FX0+FXE)-FXW/(FXW+FX0))

                if inb == 3:
                    M[A0[i,j,k],A0[i,j,k]] = 1/FZ0*(FZA/(FZ0+FZA)-FZG/(FZG+FZ0))

                if inb == 1:
                    M[A0[i,j,k],AN.ravel(order='F')[A0[i,j,k]]] = 1/FY0*FY0/(FY0+FYN)
                    M[A0[i,j,k],AS.ravel(order='F')[A0[i,j,k]]] = -1/FY0*FY0/(FY0+FYS)

                if inb == 2:
                    M[A0[i,j,k],AE.ravel(order='F')[A0[i,j,k]]] = 1/FX0*FX0/(FX0+FXE)
                    M[A0[i,j,k],AW.ravel(order='F')[A0[i,j,k]]] = -1/FX0*FX0/(FX0+FXW)

                # Account for wall Dirichlet (no-slip) condition in the wall-normal direction
                if inb == 3:
                    if AG.ravel(order='F')[A0[i,j,k]] >= 0:
                        M[A0[i,j,k],AG.ravel(order='F')[A0[i,j,k]]] = -1/FZ0*FZ0/(FZ0+FZG)
                    else:
                        M[A0[i,j,k],A0[i,j,k]] = 1/FZ0*(FZA/(FZ0+FZA)-FZG/(FZG+FZ0) + \
                                                 FZ0/(FZG+FZ0))

                    if AA.ravel(order='F')[A0[i,j,k]] < N1*N2*(N3-2):
                        M[A0[i,j,k],AA.ravel(order='F')[A0[i,j,k]]] = 1/FZ0*FZ0/(FZ0+FZA)

                    else:
                        M[A0[i,j,k],A0[i,j,k]] = 1/FZ0*(FZA/(FZ0+FZA)-FZG/(FZG+FZ0) - \
                                                 FZ0/(FZA+FZ0))

    M = sp.csc_matrix(M, copy=False)

    return M
```

If I call the above function, I get below error. Also, I get a warning related to spdiag object. I think scipy objects are not supported by Numba. But the below warning is related to the for loop. What is this error related to?

```
File "<ipython-input-5-66816b729db2>", line 13:
def ThreeDChannel_Differentiate1(N1,N2,N3,FX,FY,FZ,
    <source elided>

    for k in inz-1:
    ^

  self.func_ir.loc))
/home/suraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py:734: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should make it clear that you are using `scipy.sparse` code (`spdiags` and `lil_matrix`, `csc_matrix`).  You are right that `numba` doesn't have any `nopython` code for this; sparse matrices are not `numpy` subclasses.  What is `inz`?  The location of the warning might not be significant.

Comment: Is this some sort of finite difference or finite element stiffness matrix?  When I worked with FEA in MATLAB, I put a lot of effort into 'vectorized' evaluation of the `coo_matrix((data,(row,col))` style of inputs.  `lil` is optimized for element assignment, but it is better to collect all inputs into `row` etc arrays first.   You could probably do that with `@njit`.  Don't ask `numba` to create/modify/access sparse matrices.  (Some key parts of `sparse` code are written in `cython`.)

Comment: yes, this is a finite difference code. spdiags, lil_matirx is from scipy.sparse library. inz is a one-dimensional array that has an int64 data type. Thank you.